# How to select checkboxes with same classes, but only inside the same Fieldset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So I've been struggling with this issue where I am going to create several checkbox groups which I wish to use the same general classes for efficiency, but I decided to use a kind of "Rating System" where by selecting the one of the 5 checkboxes from one of the fieldsets would check or uncheck the other checkboxes.

**Ex: By checking the 3 checkbox, 1, 2, and 3 would check, but 4 and 5 would uncheck.**

However, since I have many fieldsets on the page, they aare interfering with each other. This is what I have in HTML:

```
<p>Example 1</p>
<fieldset id="field1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkOne" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkTwo" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkThree" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFour" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFive" />
</fieldset>

<p>Example 2</p>
<fieldset id="field2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkOne" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkTwo" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkThree" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFour" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFive" />
</fieldset>
```

With the following Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".checkOne").click(function() {
    jQuery('.checkOne').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkTwo').prop('checked', false);
    jQuery('.checkThree').prop('checked', false);
    jQuery('.checkFour').prop('checked', false);
    jQuery('.checkFive').prop('checked', false);
});
jQuery(".checkTwo").click(function() {
    jQuery('.checkOne').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkTwo').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkThree').prop('checked', false);
    jQuery('.checkFour').prop('checked', false);
    jQuery('.checkFive').prop('checked', false);
});
jQuery(".checkThree").click(function() {
    jQuery('.checkOne').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkTwo').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkThree').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkFour').prop('checked', false);
    jQuery('.checkFive').prop('checked', false);
});
jQuery(".checkFour").click(function() {
    jQuery('.checkOne').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkTwo').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkThree').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkFour').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkFive').prop('checked', false);
});
jQuery(".checkFive").click(function() {
    jQuery('.checkOne').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkTwo').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkThree').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkFour').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('.checkFive').prop('checked', true);
});
</script>
```

So as I said. My problem is that it works, however, Example1 interfers with Example2. Is there a way to do that, however, making the jQuery only work within the same Fieldsets?

Comment: why don't you use `<input type="radio">` ?

Comment: [«Radio buttons let a user select ONE of a limited number of choices»](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) This is not what OP wants.

Comment: Radios didn't do this exactly. Think of a 5-star rating system.
When clicking the 3rd star, the 1st and the 2nd light up. I just wanted to make that. But several times on the same page.

Comment: just you can add parent name/id to the selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```js
$('#field1 input, #field2 input').click(function() {
  $(this).prop('checked', true).siblings().prop('checked', false).end().addBack().prevAll().prop('checked', true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Example 1</p>
<fieldset id="field1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkOne" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkTwo" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkThree" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFour" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFive" />
</fieldset>

<p>Example 2</p>
<fieldset id="field2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkOne" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkTwo" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkThree" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFour" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFive" />
</fieldset>
```

The way it works is upon clicking an input, the keeps the input checked, unchecks all the siblings, then checks all the siblings that come before the one checked. While not affecting other groups.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Nicely written, however, am I wrong in saying that clicking on a checked item should uncheck that item?  Isn't that how checkboxes are supposed to work?  In other words, if I check the fourth box, then click the 2nd checkbox (which is now checked) shouldn't the 2nd checkbox uncheck?

Comment: @RonRoyston - Normally yes, however the OP is emulating a star rating system and doesn't want that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to have classes on your checkboxes...
See this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/snnrw3qt/).

Use this :

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    $(this).prevUntil("fieldset").prop('checked', true);    // check all previous checkboxes in the same fieldset
    $(this).nextUntil("fieldset").prop('checked', false);   // uncheck all next checkboxes in the same fieldset
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that clicking on the checkboxes only effect the checkboxes under the same parent fieldset, you can modify your functions like below

```
 jQuery(".checkOne").click(function() {
     var $field = $(this).parent();
     $field.find('.checkOne').prop('checked', true);
     $field.find('.checkTwo').prop('checked', false);
     $field.find('.checkThree').prop('checked', false);
     $field.find('.checkFour').prop('checked', false);
     $field.find('.checkFive').prop('checked', false);
 });
```

But I noticed several other issues with this approach. Like even if you click on that checkbox again, you will not be able to unselect it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but you can limit your selectors in multiple ways with jquery:

```
jQuery('#field2').find('.check1');
```

or:

```
jQuery('#field2 .check1');
```

Additional Reading: [full jquery selector documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, it is the way work for me.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e){
  var parent = this.parentNode.children
  $(parent).attr('checked', false)
  var index = Array.from(parent).indexOf(this) 
  var selection = Array.from(parent).slice(0, index +1).map(function(item){
    item.checked = true
  })
  
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Example 1</p>
<fieldset id="field1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkOne" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkTwo" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkThree" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFour" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFive" />
</fieldset>

<p>Example 2</p>
<fieldset id="field2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkOne" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkTwo" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkThree" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFour" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFive" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```js
var doc = document;
var forca = doc.getElementsByName('forca');
var destreza = doc.getElementsByName('destreza');
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(this.checked){
      check(this.className, this.name);
    } else {
      //alert('i fired');
      uncheck(this.className, this.name);
    }
  });
}

function check(number,name){
  number = numberizer(number);  
  if(name==='forca'){
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      forca[i].checked = true;
    }    
  }
  if(name==='destreza'){
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      destreza[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
}

function uncheck(number,name){
  number = numberizer(number);
  if(name==='forca'){
    for (var i = number; i < 5; i++) {
      forca[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
  if(name==='destreza'){
    for (var i = number; i < 5; i++) {
      destreza[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}

function numberizer(number){
  switch (number) {
    case "checkOne":
        return 1;
        break;
    case "checkTwo":
        return 2;
        break;
    case "checkThree":
        return 3;
        break;
    case "checkFour":
        return 4;
        break;
    case "checkFive":
        return 5;
        break;
  } 
}
```

```html
<p>Example 1</p>
<fieldset id="field1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkOne" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkTwo" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkThree" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFour" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="forca" class="checkFive" />
</fieldset>

<p>Example 2</p>
<fieldset id="field2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkOne" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkTwo" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkThree" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFour" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="destreza" class="checkFive" />
</fieldset>
```